# div superposition and center

Tags: html, css

I'm using google maps API and try to set the generated map as a background.

This is my HTML

```
<div class="content">
  <div class="map"></div>
  <div class="element"></div>
</div>
```

The CSS

```
.content {
  position: relative;
  height: 500px;
}

.map {
  position: absolute;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
}

.element {
  position: absolute;
  width: 900px;
  margin-left: auto;
  margin-right: auto;
  z-index: 1;
}
```

The site is supposed to look like this

```
|-------------------------------------|
|                                     |
|                                     |
|                                     | <- Other content
|                                     |
|-------------------------------------|
|.map |-------------------------|     |
|     |.element                 |     | <- The concerned content (.content)
|     |                         |     |
|     |-------------------------|     |
|-------------------------------------|
```

But the result is not the same. A margin left auto does not work of course. The superposition is ok, the right margin too, but how I can do for the left margin? My site has to be always centered.

Thank you.

Solution from Allan:

```
.content {
  position: relative;
  height: 500px;
}

.map {
  position: absolute;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;

  z-index: 0;
}

.element {
  position: relative;

  width: 900px;
  margin-left: auto;
  margin-right: auto;
  z-index: 1;
}
```

Comment: Left and right margins of `auto` will work on absolutely positioned and explicitly-sized blocks if you set the `left` and `right` to 0.  However, if the width of the screen is smaller than 900px - it will not center the block.  All in all, using negative margins, as shown by @Niels Keurentjes, is probably the best and most portable way to center an absolute element.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use:

```
.element {
  left:50%;
  margin-left:-450px;
  position:absolute;
  z-index:1;
}
```

Since the element is 900px wide (explicitly declared) you are positioning it 450px left of the center this way - centering the entire element.

Keep in mind that this gives some unexpected results when the browser shrinks below 900px width - you'll need to catch that with a media query if relevant.

Answer (score 1):

Margin auto wont work when the dom element have position as absolute.

If the parent have a specific width value, you should play with the top and left attributes your you .element item.

another way is to set the map's z-index to Zero (0) or a negative value, then, just set the .element to position relative, then margin could be used with auto values.

Give it a try.

and If you need, I could create a jsfiddle for you, but I will need your map code as well

Comment: It works, I have added your solution in my post. This is the right way?

Comment: There are different ways to solve this and many other things, this is one. if you could provide the code you are working with I could take a look and let you know if everything looks ok

Comment: With Niels Keurentjes's solution, I can add a margin-top, not with yours, because, the margin is also applied to the map.